# DevExtreme Angular DataGrid - Customise grouping panel and actions

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular

We would like to have much better control over the data grid grouping look and feel and behaviour.

For starters we would like to control the way the grouping panel looks - possibly create a custom panel.

Also, while we would like to preserve the ability to drag and drop columns to and from the grouping panel, we need to ability to cancel the default behaviour (for example, cancel ungrouping if drop was done on a certain column or at a certain time).

Can we do that?

What is the best approach for doing it?

Also, as a last resort, we are considering overriding the built-in behaviour. We are using the devextreme-angular library. Can we override the original devextreme js modules (e.g. providing a custom grouping controller) without recompiling all the code of both libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom data source for achieving such a functionality in devextreme.
A data grid uses a custom store which provides us with all the operations performed on grid and we need to handle those operations and provide the data in required format to the grid.
Whenever you will ungroup a column, it will give the info about the column in loadoptions and you can handle the ungrouping there by returning.
Also if you want to disable grouping for a particular column you can set the property in the column object **allowGrouping = false**, which will disable grouping on that particular column.

For more info on custom data source, refer this link
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CustomDataSource/jQuery/Light/

I have myself used it in angular.